# Which is the best way to plot graph in iphone?

Tags: ios4, core-plot, graph-drawing

I saw some Core-plot sample. Is there anything equivalent that will do my task easily? I also want to know feasibility with Core-plot in iPhone. (any issues with core-plot)

I want to have multi-colored **vertical bar chart**. Is it possible to customize Core-plot framework. Using only one barplot can we have multiple segment on it.

Thank you.
Naveen Thunga
[image]

Comment: Core Plot works fine on iOS. What type of plot are you trying to make?

Comment: Eric, I ve updated my question. Can you please help me on this? I did a sample using multiple barplot.

Comment: Are the colors intended to correspond to stacked bars, or are they merely decoration?

Comment: yeap... It corresponds to stacked bars, values coming from server.

Comment: I got to know how give space b/n 2 bar plots. Now my requirement is like i need to draw a line in each plot bar as shown in fig. Can you please help on this?

Comment: Eric, I ve more question to you. Can we have gradient colors on our bar plot as shown in Image(above).Is this possible to customize bar plot like this?

Comment: Sure--set the bar fill using a gradient instead of a solid color.

Comment: Using gradient i can have only 2 colors. (Beginning & Ending). How can i add 3 colors effect? One more thing i felt like "It is better to pass only one plot to draw this barplot image". Can you pls clarify this?

Comment: You can use the `-addColorStop:atPosition:` method to create gradients  with more colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a stacked bar plot, you need to make multiple plots, one for each segment. On all but the bottom plot, set `barBasesVary` to YES. The datasource will ask for a third field called `CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase` which is the base value for the bar. You will have to do the stacking calculations yourself.

The horizontal lines can be drawn using an additional bar plot. Give the bars a short height (tip - base). You can make the width wider than the others if you want--each plot is independent.

The space between the bars depends on several factors. By default, bar widths are specified in data coordinates. For example, if the bar locations are one unit apart, a bar width of 0.5 will make the bar width and the space between the bars equal; a bar width of 0.75 will make the space 1/3 of the bar width. The actual width in pixels depends on the size of the graph and how many bars are visible (determined by the plot range along that axis). If `barWidthsAreInViewCoordinates` is YES, then bar widths are given in pixels which keeps them the same apparent width as the plot range changes, but the space between them will change with the plot range.

Comment: Hi Eric, I ve one question for you. Is it possible to get CPTBarPlot's tip point value(CGPoint value). Can you please guide me on this?

Comment: Make a new question for this query so others can find it later. Short answer is to use the plot space.